# Content's Texts going over footer div

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML Code, If I have a lot of text inside my div called content, the footer div doesn't move downward and the texts go over my footer div.

To see the problem, please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/LhzrQ/

Could You please tell me how to solve the problem?

```
    <div id="container" style="width:500px">

        <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
            <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Main Title of Web Page</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
            <b>Menu</b><br>
            HTML<br>
            CSS<br>
            JavaScript
        </div>

        <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;width:400px;float:left;">
            HyperText Markup Language (HTML) is the main markup language for displaying web pages and other information that can be displayed in a web browser.
            HTML is written in the form of HTML elements consisting of tags enclosed in angle brackets (like <html>), within the web page content. HTML tags most commonly come in pairs like <h1> and </h1>, although some tags, known as empty elements, are unpaired, for example <img>. The first tag in a pair is the start tag, the second tag is the end tag (they are also called opening tags and closing tags). In between these tags web designers can add text, tags, comments and other types of text-based content. The purpose of a web browser is to read HTML documents and compose them into visible or audible web pages. The browser does not display the HTML tags, but uses the tags to interpret the content of the page.

        </div>

        <div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">
            Copyright © W3Schools.com
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete the height element of the content div.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/LhzrQ/1/

Answer (score 1):

Working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LhzrQ/8/)

remove the `fixed height` to the `content` div. it will work .